# Gmail SMTP XOAUTH2 error: JWT has expired

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, smtp, gmail, google-api-dotnet-client

Yesterday I created a ClientID & Client Secret (using [this](https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/sdk/html/object_oauth.htm) guide) to authenticate a desktop application (C#/.NET) to send emails from a Gmail account.

My method, which authenticates and sends an email, looks as follows:

```
public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int> SendEmailOAuth2Async(string sFromMailAddress, string sClientID, string sClientSecret)
    {
        var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = sClientID,
            ClientSecret = sClientSecret
        },
        new[] { "email", "profile", "https://mail.google.com/" },
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None
        ) ;

        var jwtPayload = GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(credential.Token.IdToken).Result;
        var username = jwtPayload.Email;

        var mailMessage = new MimeMessage();
        mailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("from name", sFromMailAddress));
        mailMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("to name", "someone@outlook.com"));
        mailMessage.Subject = "Automated Mail with OAuth";
        mailMessage.Body = new TextPart("plain")
        {
            Text = "Hello"
        };



        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);

            // use the access token
            var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(sFromMailAddress, credential.Token.AccessToken);
            client.Authenticate(oauth2);

            client.Send(mailMessage);

            client.Disconnect(true);
        }

        return 0;

    }
```

Yesterday, sending an email with this method worked. Today, I get a

> **System.AggregateException:** 'One or more errors occured. (JWT has
> expired.)'

I am new to OAuth and tokens. What can I do to get this to work again?

Comment: Your using the Google .net client library to create an access token for use with the Smtp server.   Well go you i didn't even think that was possible.  Im curious as to why you are passing the IdToken and not the access token

Comment: You mean when I'm assigning `jwtPayload`? Because that's what the example code I found for that did. See https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/sdk/html/object_oauth.htm, under heading "Use client id and client secret to get access token".

Comment: Very impressive i never thought of using the library in this manner.     I'm just wondering which JWT is expired. the thing is using the Idtoken seams weird as its not going to refresh unless you are using open id connect and the user is logged in.   using filedata store to refresh is just going to refresh the access token using the refresh token stored.  Your not going to get a new IdToken unless the user logs in.

Comment: Can you include a [example] i cant even get your code to compile there's something missing.

Comment: Have you solved ? I'm in same situation. First time go then JWT is Expired.

Comment: Your JWT token sounds very similar to what I know as the "Access token".  An Access token is only valid for perhaps an hour and then you need a new one.  There is another token known as the "Refresh token" which you can use to obtain a new Access token.

Answer (score 0):

After generating the credentials object using **GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync**, I then attempted to run

`GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(credential.Token.IdToken).Result`

but was met with "Expired JWT." Using this method call-

`await credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None);`

the **credential.Token** object was updated and **I then was able to call GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync method** (using the same credential object) **successfully.**

Thank you Garth J Lancaster on different website. Not sure if I'm allowed to link from here.

Comment: Not only are you _allowed_ to link from here, but you are also _encouraged_ to when your work was inspired by or derived from external sources. Generally, the only time you need to be worried about linking is when a) the answer _relies_ on the external link (and, thus, will become useless if the page the link points to is removed); or b) the link is a form of self-promotion (and especially if you're not disclosing your interest).